# Why only perpendicular or parallel forces are counted?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

Usually in physics, we take components of a vector (let's say force) to find the answer.

Eg:- while finding force to calculate torque we find Fsin(theta)[image]

There are numerous such examples where we take a component of force to get a vector which either perpendicular (sine) or parallel to the surface.

But technically force is a push or pull so it shouldn't really matter if we take non perpendicular force.

Then why is it necessary to calculate the components of forces?.

Comment: I'm disappointed that your teacher hasn't explained this to you. Is your teacher a physics person? If so, go ask them. If not, go ask the principal why the teacher isn't a physics person.

Comment: He is a physics teacher, he did engineering. He never explains these small things. He just gives some tricks and notes to memorize.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to go through that. Memorizing is not a good way to learn physics. Physics is NOT a bunch of tricks, but it's a set of principles built on a few foundational axioms.  Do your best to RESPECTFULLY get him to explain some of the underlying reasons for the tricks. Don't go too deep, but a single layer explanation may make for a better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then why is it necessary to calculate the components of forces?.

The short answer is we may need to calculate the vertical and/or horizontal components of a force to determine what the force does.

> But technically force is a push or pull so it shouldn't really matter
>   if we take non perpendicular force.

See the diagram below of a box on a surface with friction. Say we want to know how much work the force $F$ does moving the box a distance $d$ against friction. We can't determine this unless we calculate *both the vertical and horizontal components* of $F$.

We need to know the vertical component ($F$ sin θ) because this, together with the weight of the box ($mg$) will give us the force normal to the surface, $N$. We need $N$ to determine the kinetic friction force $f$.

Then we need to now the horizontal component of $F$ ($F$ cos θ) because this, with the friction force $f$ will give us the net force acting in the horizontal direction. That net force times the distance the box moves gives us the work done by $F$.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: That was helpful. I just have one small question. Suppose the block in your picture lifts up exactly in the direction of force F, so will we calculate component in that case or just multiply with F.

Comment: @User Obviously if $F$ sin θ was greater than $mg$ the block would lift off the surface and there  would be no friction work. My example was intended that $F$ sin θ < $mg$ to illustrate the need to determine both horizontal and vertical components of $F$ to determine work against friction.